# HTML, JQuery game based on Arraylist

Tags: jquery, html, arraylist

I have a game that is based on a 9x9 grid array in which the user attempts to escape but at random positioning in the array there are blocks in which the user cannot move to or it will end the game. 3=user, 1=safe, 2=wall, 0=safezone.
essentially I want to have a JQuery/JavaScript in which the user can select a difficulty and it will randomly put a certain amount of 2's in random positions.
How would I go about doing this? based on IF statements from difficulty buttons
`board = [[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ], 
         [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
         [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ] ];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works ok for me. 
If you check you console, you will see that the board is being updated with 2's randomly.

*Change the quantity of 2's being inserted by updating the vars 'difA - difD'.*

**HTML**

```
 <select id="selectDif">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**JQ/JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectDif").change(function(){
    var getDif = $(this).val();

    var board = [[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ], 
                [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ], 
                [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ], 
                [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ], 
                [ 0,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,0 ], 
                [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ], 
                [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
                [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 ],
                [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ] ];

    var difA = 10;
    var difB = 15;
    var difC = 20;
    var difD= 5;

       switch(getDif) {
             case 1:
             doThis(difA)
             break;
             case 2:
             doThis(difB)
             break;
             case 3:
             doThis(difC)
             break;
             default:
              doThis(difD)
             }  
       function doThis(e){
             var boardRows = board.length;
             var boardRowsLength = board[0].length;
             var difficulty = e;
             for(i=0; i<e; i++){
                          var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * boardRows)); 
                          var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * boardRowsLength) ); 
                          board[x][y] = 2;
             }
              console.log(board[0],board[2],board[2],board[3],board[4],board[5],'...etc');
             }
     });  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Mark,this seems to be exactly what I need but i'm having trouble implementing it into my HTML. I have been asked to implement all of this in function `startGame(difficulty)` and I am not allowed to edit the actual array. I am also having difficult linking each difficultly with previous made simple <button> s. any idea?

Comment: Can you post everything you have in a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gLc02rsu/ i've tried to put it on JSFiddle but due to it being heavily local png based makes it difficult

Comment: @TBEZFTM   I'll have to come back to this tonight... I want to get this working, but I'm busy at work. Just curious, is this a school project?